# How to duplicate selected text or lines multiple times in sublimet text?

Tags: plugins, duplicates, sublimetext

If i want to duplicate selected text n times, i can just hit ctrl+d so many times. But the question is i need to count 1 to n when performing the action.
Is there a better way to do this? any plugin(textpastry or something else) wiil do?

Answer (score 0):

Try **[Paste​ Repeater](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PasteRepeater)** - a Sublime Text plugin for pasting your clipboard multiple times.

Usage: **Ctrl + Shift + V**

Paste​ Repeater is a Sublime Text 3 plugin that will let you paste your system's clipboard into a file multiple times. So instead of hitting Ctrl+V two dozen times, you can use this plugin to tell Sublime Text to paste your clipboard as many times as you'd like in a single command.

**What Happens**
The Sublime Text input panel will ask you how many times you'd like to paste your clipboard into the editor - **Input field**

Your system's clipboard will be pasted into the editor at the cursor's current location the number of times you request. Values are rounded down to the lowest whole number.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PasteRepeater